# There does not exist rational numbers $x$ and $y$ such that $x^y$ is a positive integer and $y^x$ is a negative integer

Tags: proof-writing, rational-numbers

I want to prove or disprove:

There does not exist rational numbers $x$ and $y$ such that $x^y$ is a positive integer and  $y^x$ is a negative integer.

For the integers $-3$ and $4$, $(-3)^4 = 81$ and $4^{-3} = 1/64$.

There seems to be no rational numbers satisfying the condition.

Can you comment on this?

Comment: \begin{align}
1^{-1} &= 1 \\
(-1)^1 &= -1
\end{align}

Comment: *Can you comment on this ?* - [Yes, I can](http://newsbusters7.s3.amazonaws.com/images/2013/June/Yes%20We%20Can.jpg). If $~\big\{x,y\big\}\cap\big\{0,\pm1\big\}=\varnothing,~$ then there are no $($rational$)$ solutions.

Answer (score 1):

If $y^x$ is a negative integer,
then $y$ must be a negative integer
(or else $y^x > 0$)
and $x$ must be a positive integer
(or else $0 < |y^x| < 1$).

But then
$0 < x^y < 1$,
so $x^y$ is not
a positive integer.